# In javascript, how can I ignore blank lines while uploading a csv file?

Tags: javascript, csv, blank-line

In a csv file that has some blank lines in between and the last line is blank as well, how can I ignore them or let's say, jump to the next not empty line?

column1; column2; column3

value1; value2; value3

__________________this line is empty

value7; value8; value9

__________________this line (the last one) is empty

I obtain the file content:

```
var fileString = evt.target.result;
```

Than I do this to analize every single line and then to display it on my website:

```
var lines = fileString.split("\r\n");
```

Is there any possibility to write a loop that checks the blank lines and replace them? Like this:

```
var pattern = /\r?\n\r?\n/g;

for(var i = 0; i < fileString.length; i++){
  if(lines === null){
     lines.replace(pattern, '\n');
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to remove blank lines from a string? Because it has to be available to you as a string before you can manipulate it in Javascript. That or you have to process the file in a buffered fashion and remove extra lines as you go.

Comment: Exactly, it is available to me as a string and I want either to ignore them or to remove them. I want to import a csv file to my webpage and when I do that, one can see all the blank rows and even the last one, what I basically  don't need.

Comment: Why not remove the extra lines *before* doing `fileString.split("\r\n")`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a blank line in between lines, that means you have two line terminators in a row. Most of the time that means you have `\n\n` but on Windows, line terminators are preceded by a carriage return which means `\r\n\r\n`. To get rid of empty lines, replace any double terminators by single terminators.

```js
var input = 'a,b,c\r\n' +
            'd,e,f\r\n' +
            '\n' +
            'g,h,i\n' +
            '\n';
var pattern = /\r?\n\r?\n/g;
console.log(input.replace(pattern, '\n'));
```

This regular expression will match either `\r\n` or just `\n` (the `\r?` means 0 or 1 matches of `\r`) then using the global flag (`g`) you can [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) every match in the string with the string you pass as the second argument (`'\n'`).

**Warning:** Attempting to [destroy Terminators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(franchise)) may result in a long-term battle for humanity.

Comment: Hmm, I tried this and it doesn't work :/ Neither the line in the middle nor the last one has been replaced.

Comment: @C.R. You're going to have to give me some sample input then because, as you can see, this works for the problem you described.

Comment: No, you need to be a bit more subtle - 1: Replace \r\n with \n - 2: Replace \n+ (ie: 1 or more \n) with \n - 3: Replace starts with \n (regex /^\n/g) with null.

Comment: Sorry - I meant replace with "" (blank string) not null.

Comment: @TonyDuffill I wouldn't call that more subtle. It would also work but would be slower since you have to process the string twice.

Comment: @Mike C, I added something to my post, could you take a look? Thanks

Comment: @Mike C, yes, accept it's slower, I was trying to lay out the process in simple steps. Your neater regex is better but it still doesn't remove any starting \n in case the input begins with a blank line.